# Deleting Document Couchbase Lite iOS

Tags: ios, couchbase-lite

For some reason when i call `[document delete:&e]` the document is not deleted in couchbase. I mean i even check the value of `document.is_deleted` and `document.is_gone`. Yet for some reason my document is not being deleted. Is there an error with couchbase lite right now for iOS? Here ill post my exact code.

```
- (BOOL)deleteOldSettingsDocument{

BOOL old_settings_document_deleted = FALSE;
CBLDocument *v1_setting_document = [self v1SettingsDocument];
if(v1_setting_document){
    NSError *e = nil;
    if(![v1_setting_document deleteDocument:&e]){
        NSLog(@"Error deleting old settings document");
        NSLog(@"%@",e.localizedDescription);
    }
    else{
        old_settings_document_deleted = TRUE;
    }
}
return old_settings_document_deleted;
```

}

Comment: `NSError *error; [v1_setting_document save:&error];`?

Comment: Are you still able to retrieve the document?  How do you know that it is not deleted?

Comment: Does someone have updates on this? I have checked sqlite file size is not reducing after deleting document?